# Django Immediently expiring sessions

Tags: django, session, authentication, django-authentication

I'm experiencing an issue with Django and Django Auth. From time to time the login page will not allow users to login. When the user presses login (on the /admin login form OR any custom login form) the page simply refreshes. After debugging further it seems that it is creating a session and then expiring it (somehow). Has anyone experienced this type of behavior with Django Auth?

Thanks,

cory

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had this problem.

But so, you should check your apps, middleware, and context processor specifications in your settings.py file. You'll want to be sure the following are in place (in addition to whatever else you need for your specific app):

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    # ...
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    # ...
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    # ...
    "django.core.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
    # ...
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    # ...
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    # ...
)
```

... make sure that's all good to go and see if your problem persists. Good luck.